# Distribution of time in state for a Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I fully understand how to derive the expected time in a given state for a Markov chain, but I can't seem to derive the distribution. Specifically I'm interested in finding the distribution of time spent in some state as a function of the initial state and number of steps or amount of time. All of the chains I'm interested in have tridiagonal transition matrices and are aperiodic.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit to add context:

The observed effect in my system is a non-linear function of the time spent in each state, so its not sufficient for me to know the expected time spent in each state - I need the distribution. As time goes to infinity, I know that the variance of the distribution goes to 0 - that is to say, if a "particle" spends infinite time in the system they will be in every state for exactly the expected amount of time. However, I'm interested in earlier time points.

The distribution I'm looking for should be different for different transition matrices even if the equilibrium state is the same. If a "particle" samples each state more quickly than another, the distribution of time spent in the various states should be tighter around the known mean, which is always going to be the expected time spent in the state.

I hope this makes sense. My background is in chemistry, not math (obviously) so its sometimes difficult for me to express myself with formalism.

Comment: You mean the distribution of the hitting time of some state $a$? This can be computed using a similar recursion to the recursion for the expected hitting time. $P(T=n \mid X_0=i)=\sum_j P(T=n-1 \mid X_0=j) P(X_1=j \mid X_0)=i$ for $n>0$ and then you have the boundary condition $P(T=0 \mid X_0=a)=1$.

Comment: Are you interested in the stationary distribution or the transient behavior of the process?

Comment: Other plausible interpretations are the time spent in $a$ before leaving $a$ (this is simple for a homogeneous chain) and the time spent in $a$ over time (which has no simple expression, but can be written in terms of eigenvalues/eigenvectors and then approximated by truncation).

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I mean the distribution of the amount of time spent in state n after some time t given some starting state m. I know that the average particle will spend the expected time in each state, but in my system the effect of the states is non-linear so in order to determine the total effect I need to know something about the distributions, not just the expected value. For my case, the system is stable overall but I still want to know for a given "particle" the distribution of time spent in each state.

Comment: I know I'm not explaining myself particularly well. so I'll try to add context to the question

Comment: So you want the distribution of the number of visits to each state in the first $t$ time steps? This has no simple expression. In fact I don't think you can even nicely write it in terms of, for example, powers of the transition probability matrix, because you need to know how the random variables $1(X_i=k)$ and $1(X_j=k)$ depend on one another in order to resolve the distribution of their sum.

Comment: Is this a discrete-time or continuous-time Markov chain?